# How get 400 Bad Request in variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have answer from my REST - result = <400 Bad Request>

And i want show this error for user using angularJS.

I have fuction in controller

```
 $scope.update = function (id) {
                Topic.get({id: id}, function (result) {
                    $scope.name = result;
                    $('#saveTopicModal').modal('show');
                    console.log(result);
                });
            };
```

Please help - how get error in some variable and then show this variable.
Thank you

Comment: what equals is ```id``` ?

Comment: id - its intereger - .get method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get access to the error you have to define an error handler as in the description of the angular $resource API.

> ```
>                     $scope.error = error;
> ```

```
$scope.update = function (id) {
                Topic.get({id: id}, function (result) {
                    $scope.name = result;
                    $('#saveTopicModal').modal('show');
                    console.log(result);
                }, function (error) {                        
                    console.log(error);
                    $scope.error = error;
                });
            };
```